# Matlab, find common elements of two cell arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, element

I have two cell arrays, the sizes are 1x20033 and 1x19. Let's call these two cell arrays as A and B. I want to compare each cell of A with each cell of B to see if there is any common element.

Finally, I need to build a binary matrix and put one when there is a match.

I tried this:

```
BinaryMatrix=zeros(20033,19);

for i=1:1:20033

    for j=1:1:19 
        match=find(ismember(A{i},B{j}));        
        if match==1  
            BinaryMatrix(i,j)= 1;        
         end
    end
end
```

but I faced this error: "Input A of class double and input B of class cell must be
cell arrays of strings, unless one is a string."

Please tell me What should I do to solve it?

Comment: Replace `find` by `any`? Also, what do the cells contain?

Comment: Each cell contains a string of words. The length of these strings are different. One might be 20 and the other 300.

Comment: Did you try using `intersect`?

Comment: I replaced 'find' by 'any' but it didn't work. The same error appeared.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by intersect? How could I use it?

Comment: I'll write an answer for you.

Comment: What is an "element": a letter or a word? `ismember` will work letter-wise, but not word-wise

Comment: Each element is a word. Now I understand why 'ismember' didn't work.

Comment: @user36729 - I wrote an answer.  I assumed that your string of words is separated by spaces.  Please let me know if that answer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you have almost works.  What I would recommend you do is split up the strings found in `A` and `B` by spaces.  As such, `A` and `B` would then be cell arrays of elements where each element in `A` or `B` is **a single word**.  The spaces will serve as delimiters for separating out the words.

Once you do this, use [`intersect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) to see if there are any common words between the words in `A` and the words in `B`.  `intersect` works by considering two arrays (these can be numeric arrays, cell arrays, etc.) `C` and `D` as sets, and it returns the set intersection between these two arrays.

In our case, `C` and `D` would be a cell array of words separated by spaces from `A` and `B`.  `intersect(C,D)` will return a cell array of strings where each element in the output is a string found in **both** `C` and `D`.  As such, should this cell array be non-empty, we have found at least one common word between `C` and `D`.  If this is the case, then set your binary flag at the location of your matrix to 1.  In other words:

```
BinaryMatrix = false(20033,19);

for i=1:1:20033
    for j=1:1:19 
        Asplit = strsplit(A{i});
        Bsplit = strsplit(B{j});
        if (~isempty(intersect(Asplit, Bsplit)))
            BinaryMatrix(i,j)= true;        
        end
    end
end
```

You'll notice that I have changed your matrix from `zeros(20033,19)`, to `false(20033,19)`.  The reason why is because by doing `zeros`, you are allocating 8 bytes per number in your matrix as this will create your matrix in double precision.  By doing `false`, this will be a `logical` matrix instead, and you are allocating 1 byte per number.  Seeing as how you want `BinaryMatrix` to be either `true` or `false`, don't use `double` - use `logical`.  I don't know how large both cell arrays are, and so doing this will cut down your memory consumption by 8.

## Minor Note

`strsplit` is only available from R2013a and onwards.  If you have a version of MATLAB that is R2012b and lower, replace `strsplit` with `regexp`.  As such, you would replace the two lines in the `for` loop with:

```
Asplit = regexp(A{i}, ' ', 'split');
Bsplit = regexp(B{j}, ' ', 'split');
```

Comment: @LuisMendo - I'm standing on the shoulders of giants :) I've only learned from the best, including you.  Thank you!

Comment: Hahaha, thanks! Great invention, this Stack Overflow